# Transformation of array with cumulative values

Tags: python, pandas, list, transformation

In python, I have a list `list` such as the one in the first column, and I would like to transform it in a list such as the second column.

```
1 -> 1
1    1
1    3
2    0
3    0
1    1
1    5
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
1    1
1    1
```

The transformation would work as follow:

The "background value" is 1, that is generally kept in the transformation. Sometimes blocks of consecutive numbers appear, for example from the third element we have a "1,2,3" block. The maximum value of the block is taken and assigned to the first element of the block (that always is a 1), while the other elements are assigned to 0.

At the moment I am doing the transformation through a loop that iterates each element, but I would like to improve the code and work on the whole list at once, is there a way?
For example I can find all the maximum values by converting it to a `pandas.Series` and performing `list.diff(periods=-1)` and masking all the non-positive values, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create virtual groups to extract the highest values for the group and broadcast it. Finally replace values by 0 when the value is not 1.

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1]
sr = pd.Series(lst)

m = sr.eq(1)
out = sr.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('max').where(m, other=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
0     1
1     1
2     3
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     5
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    1
12    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) twice:

```py
s = pd.Series(l)
s_out = s.where(s.diff(-1).ne(-1), pd.NA).bfill() \
    .where(s.eq(1), 0)
```

The first takes the difference moving backwards (as you have done) and all fills all those equal to `-1` with `pd.NA`, then backwards fills.  The second `where` then replaces the values with 0 for any row where the initial list is not `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) starting on each `1` and taking the last value of the group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,5,1,1]})

m = df['col'].eq(1)

df['out'] = df.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('last').where(m, 0)
```

Output:

```
    col  out
0     1    1
1     1    1
2     1    3
3     2    0
4     3    0
5     1    1
6     1    5
7     2    0
8     3    0
9     4    0
10    5    0
11    1    1
12    1    1
```